# Error when importing flask_socket-io : AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Tags: python, flask-socketio, eventlet

With a python file that is just:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
```

I get the error:

```
> python .\app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\{...}\server\app.py", line 127, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
  File "C:\{...}\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from socketio import socketio_manage  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\{...}\Python310\lib\site-packages\socketio\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .zmq_manager import ZmqManager
  File "C:\{...}\Python310\lib\site-packages\socketio\zmq_manager.py", line 5, in <module>
    import eventlet.green.zmq as zmq
  File "C:\{...}\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience
  File "C:\{...}\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\convenience.py", line 7, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import socket
  File "C:\{...}\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\green\socket.py", line 21, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greendns
  File "C:\{...}\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\greendns.py", line 79, in <module>
    setattr(dns, pkg, import_patched('dns.' + pkg))
  File "C:\{...}\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\greendns.py", line 61, in import_patched
    return patcher.import_patched(module_name, **modules)
  File "C:\{...}\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\patcher.py", line 132, in import_patched
    return inject(
  File "C:\{...}\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\patcher.py", line 109, in inject
    module = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, module_name.split('.')[:-1])
  File "C:\{...}\Python310\lib\site-packages\dns\namedict.py", line 35, in <module>
    class NameDict(collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

I saw in other threads that `collections.MutableMapping` has changed to `collections.abc.MutableMapping` in python >=3.1. I have tried the following solutions to no avail:

1. Upgrade dependent packages:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade wheel
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade requests
```

2. Reinstall flask-socketio

```
pip install flask-socketio
```

I tried to reinstall the eventlet dependency with upgrade:

```
pip install --upgrade eventlet
Requirement already satisfied: eventlet in c:\...\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.33.3)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.3 in c:\...\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from eventlet) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython>=1.15.0 in c:\...\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from eventlet) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\...\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from eventlet) (1.16.0)
```

None of these options work. How should I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with dnspython the latest version of dnspython does use `collections.abc.MutableMapping`, so you need to upgrade it

`pip install --upgrade dnspython`